# IEnumerable.Select() returning unexpected results

Tags: c#, azure, ienumerable

I am querying Azure Table Storage using C#, which returns an IEnumerable. I am using .Select() to get two different attributes from my result but the count of each attribute is not correct. For example:

```
IEnumerable<SomeClass> results = table.ExecuteQuery(query);
IEnumerable<DateTime> dates = results.Select(x => x.Date);
IEnumerable<double> doubles = results.Select(x => x.Doubles);
```

Every result has a date and a double value (I have verified this), so the count of each of them should be exactly the same as each other and result but they come back differently. I might have 300k results, and then 299,997 dates and 300,003 doubles.

When I do something like:

```
results.ToList();
```

and then use .Select() I get the correct results. I am trying to avoid converting the records to a list first because it takes way too long. I also want to avoid using a for loop or a foreach loop because they also take far too long.

My question is: Is there a way to use .Select() on an IEnumerable and get accurate results? Or is there another way to do this which would be very fast?

NOTE: I am plotting this data on an xy graph and for about 300k records it takes about 1 minute 30 seconds. About 90% of that time is due to a foreach loop I had. If I convert to a list first it takes even longer to process. Using the .Select() on an IEnumerable is very fast but I need reliable results and the amount of x values has to be the same as y values.

Comment: Is the date perhaps equal to `DateTime.MinValue` on some rows? Perhaps ATS is effectively skipping that?

Comment: How you check amount of rows for each query results? In both cases you return `IEnumerable` which will be executed only when you iterate it.

Comment: No. I have been entering these records in a test environment and the date is always the current date at which the data was posted.

Comment: _Using the .Select() on an IEnumerable is very fast_ - it not fast, you just postponed execution to the later, possible when you actually iterate results.

Comment: To check the results of each .Select() I executed dates.Count() and doubles.Count()

Comment: Do I have any other options to get the dates and doubles that would be quick? I have been exploring this for a quite a while because this is making load time very slow.

Comment: Does `table.ExecuteQuery(query).ToList();` will always return same amount of items? For example if you execute it two times

Comment: Yes, I get the same amount for consecutive queries.

Comment: My best tip would be to try something like `var valuePairs = results.Select(x => new { Date = x.Date, Value => x.Doubles });`. Depending on the way you need your data for the graph, this could even be the faster option as well.

Comment: @Namoshek I am getting an error on the Value => x.Doubles portion. It says Invalid anonymous type member declarative.... Am I missing something?

Comment: @Namoshek I had to change Value => to Value = and it seems to have worked. I need the get the dates and values our separately, what would be the fastest way to do so? I need to pass the values to a dataSeries that accepts 2 different parameters.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. The fastest way would be what you tried initially, which should work from my perspective, but you can also try to do above two selects on the selected `valuePairs` I suggested. If this leads to different result sizes again, then you most likely have an issue as pointed out by @JonSkeet already.

Comment: @Namoshek I was able to do 2 selects on the valuepair but when I add them to my data series, it seems to take a very long time to do so. Doing .ToList() would still be quicker. But thank you for the help! It may be impossible to speed things up but being stubborn, I refuse to believe there isn't a way haha

Comment: Do you have a way to differentiate between the time it takes to query the data and the time it takes to draw the graph? Do you add all data at once to the graph or one-by-one? (My fear here would be that the graph gets drawed for every added value.)

Comment: I add the data all at once but from my understanding this chart is made to handle millions of records. I am using SciChart.

Comment: Azure tables / SDK uses lazy enumerables. The actual http request to table service to retrieve the entities is not done when you call executequery but when you iterate over the returned Ienumerable results. That's one possibility why you see diff results as you iterate over the enumerable by select maybe the data on the table is changing?

Comment: @DoguArslan if you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure tables / SDK uses lazy enumerables. The actual http request to table service to retrieve the entities is not done when you call executequery but when you iterate over the returned Ienumerable results. That's one possibility why you see diff results as you iterate over the enumerable by select maybe the data on the table is changing?